# Proving every totally ordered and bounded lattice set is a Heyting Algebra

Tags: lattice-orders

I am trying to prove that given some bounded lattice $(L, \vee, \wedge, \top, \bot)$, where $(L, \leq )$ is a totally ordered set with 
\begin{align}
a \leq b :  a \wedge b = a 
\end{align}
Implies that $L$ is a Heyting algebra with the Heyting implication
\begin{align}
a \rightarrow b = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \top & \quad a\leq b\\
      b & \quad \text{else}
      \end{array} \right.
\end{align}
I figured that in order to prove it I need to prove that the implication satisfies

\begin{align}
 (x \wedge a) \leq b \Leftrightarrow x \leq ( a \rightarrow b)
\end{align}
However I seem to get stuck.

Comment: Of course you are absolutely right. I am trying to prove it in coq, so I guess my mind was on a different level. If you create a answer I would be delighted to mark it.

Comment: Okay, I'll change my comment to an answer, so the question can be marked answered.  By the way, I recently started learning Coq, so if you implement this proof, could you share it?  Thanks!

Comment: I will do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, according to the definition of Heyting algebra, you must check that the $\Leftrightarrow$ in your last displayed equation holds. This follows from the fact that your lattice is totally ordered, arguing by cases.

For example, suppose $x\wedge a \leq b$.

If $a\leq b$, then $a \rightarrow b$ is top, so it is certainly above $x$. 
If not $a \leq b$, then, since the lattice is totally ordered, $b< a$. This and $x\wedge a \leq b$ imply that $x$ is below $b$, hence $x \leq (a \rightarrow b)$ in this case.

The $\Leftarrow$ direction is similar.